# internal error server point to working server using load balancer or nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, 500-error, 503-error

Lets say that I have 3 physical servers with different IPs and 1 load balancer which manages the traffic between those 3 servers. We tested to stop the service of nginx in the 2 servers and the load balancer detected that and didn't use the 2 servers with nginx stopped.

My question is:
For instance that the 3 servers are up and running, and 1 server has an internal server error (any 500 internal server error). How can we avoid that 1 server that is encountering the server error? to avoid white page?

Answer (score 0):

You avoid a white page by defining a properly formatted error document with the [`error_page`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) directive instead of relying on the default error message  :)

```
   error_page 500 /errors/500.html
```

On the other hand if you want to avoid sending further requests to a node that returns errors?

Typically that is something you configure in the loadbalancer, there you want to remove a failed node from the pool of active back-end servers. The details differ between products but you need to define a health check that does more than just a TCP connect to determine if a back-end server is up and running.

The loadbalancer needs to do something a little more advanced such as an actual HTTP request and evaluate how fast and what gets returned, typically if the HTTP status/response code is 200 and/or the response body has specific content or meets a certain minimum size.

Comment: So there's an option in the load balancer to make that process where it will check first the response code before actually using that server?

Comment: @Rei Most loadbalancers have a polling mechanism to determine if the back-end server is alive and healthy, yes. In many the default checks are basic, mostly along the lines of *"is there a service listening and can an TCP connection be established?"* but more advanced checks can be configured as well. So read the manual for your loadbalancer to see what's supported and possible.

Comment: @HBruijin thanks, we will try that. I will get back to you once we tested it out. And by the way, is there a way to create a local load balancer?